# maskedextender and calenderextender in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new person in asp.net. I have one text box and one calender image button in my asp.net application. I use the masked extender to display date in the textbox like yyyy-mm--dd. Also i use the calender extender for the purpose of clicking image button it will show the date in the textbox. I use the following code.

```
                                    &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="imgdatefrom" runat="server" 
                                        ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.jpeg" Height="19px" Width="20px"  />
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblTo"  runat="server" Text="End Date" 
                                        ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="enddateval" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                                    &nbsp;<asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtDateFrom_CalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDateFrom" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" PopupButtonID="imgdatefrom"
                                                        TodaysDateFormat="yyyy d, MMMM">
                                        </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

While I executing that code and selecting date by clicking image button the selected date will not displayed in the textbox. Can anyone know how to solve the problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of MaskedExtender you just use standard TextBox Control. It will work.